# Белая полоса вверху хэдэра(отступ) при верстке. CSS

Tags: css, вёрстка

При верстке появляется полоса, при этом margin,padding установлены на 0. Даже текст имеет этот отступ. Подскажите пожалуйста причины и способы решения проблемы.
[image: вот]
Код:

```css
html,body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 815px;
    background-image:url("../images/back.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="h-wrap">
        <h1 class="headline">There is no otherplatforms for you as like</h1>
        <a href="#" class="playbtn_link">
            <img class="playbtn_icon" src="images/Playbutton.png" height="60px" width="60px" alt="play">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="button_try">try now</a>
        <P class="text">* No need to add card ditails</P>
    </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Кусочек html бы ещё увидеть. Непонятно, к чему относится класс .header. Потом, по дефолту все <p> и <h> имеют свой марджин. Их тоже обнулить надо.

Comment: Спасибо, с обнулением дефолтных марджинов p,h проблема решилась.

Comment: Возможно дело в теге H1. Проверьте Margin у этого элемента, мне помогло

Answer (score 0):

У браузеров есть свои стили. И у них стандартно есть margin у h,p,ul и т.д.
Для решения этой проблемы подключают этот css файл https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `overflow: hidden;` для `header`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 815px;
    background-image:url("http://via.placeholder.com/700x350");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="h-wrap">
        <h1 class="headline">There is no otherplatforms for you as like</h1>
        <a href="#" class="playbtn_link">
            <img class="playbtn_icon" src="images/Playbutton.png" height="60px" width="60px" alt="play">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="button_try">try now</a>
        <P class="text">* No need to add card ditails</P>
    </div>

</header>
```

Это внешние отступы заголовка *вылазят*.

Answer (score 0):

открываем инструменты разработчика => берем от тудо мышку => наводим на пустое пространство и ниже и ждем появление обертки желтого цвета, кликаем и смотрим на стили (воля по дефолту есть у тега margin, padding или что то еще).

те же действия можно делать без мышки, просто навидением на теги(дом дерево) каторые находятся тоже в инструментах разработчика => елементы(elements)